# Google Search using Perl

Tags: perl, search

I am new to Perl. please help.
I am using below script for Google Search. But Google blocked the IP address.
What is alternative way for Google Search and get URLs?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Google::Search;

my $search = Google::Search->Web(q => "rock");
my $result = $search->first;
while ($result) {
    print $result->number, " ", $result->uri, "\n";
    $result = $result->next;
}
print $search->error->reason, "\n" if $search->error;
```

Comment: So, do you have an error message?

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe you can open a web browser and look if Google wants you to fill in + submit some captcha forms. Then your IP might be unblocked, and you can try your program again.

Comment: This code works fine. But if you use it several times, Google blocks the ip stating " 403 Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see [link] http://code.google.com/apis/errors "